# How do you combine Lapply() and dbListFields() to get all column names for every table in a DATABASE?

Tags: r, odbc, lapply, sapply, rodbc

I would like to create a short Catalog for myself out of a database which would show what tables and fields are available there with the combination of SAPPLY(), LAPPLY() etc. and DBListNames.

So far I only get this far but it returns a "0" character variable:

```
catalog <- lapply(list_of_tables, function(t) dbListFields(con, name = paste0(t)))
```

So I would like to create an output like this:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|  DB TABLES |       FIELDS       |
+------------+--------------------+
| ORDERS     | "PRODUCT", "TIME"  |
| CLIENTS    | "ID", "NAME"       |
| PROMOTIONS | "DATE", "DISCOUNT" |
+------------+--------------------+
```

I haven't used these kind of loops and I would like to start it here..

Thank you for your support in advance!

Comment: Works for me on a test database with `list_of_tables = dbListTables(con)`. Where does your `list_of_tables` come from?

Comment: Hi! that works for me too I made "list_of_tables" with dbListTables(con). For this I would like to get the column names next to them separated with a comma.

Comment: So is your question now partially answered? It doesn't return `a "0" character variable: ` because you'd not specified `list_of_tables` properly? Any idea what you had done?

Comment: I got list of tables by using the dblistTables(con). It worked fine and it listed out the tables just fine.

Comment: So what were you doing wrong that resulted in you having to ask the question in the first place? Where did you get your `list_of_tables` in the question such that it returned a "0 character variable"?